# How to group by and then append or squeeze multiple rows together in df to create one row?

Tags: python, pandas

The dataset is shows a transaction id and multiple binary flags of which department the product is associated with. Transaction is not necessarily a unique id because one transaction can have multiple items from different departments.

- Example

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Trans_ID': [149857724, 149857724, 394875934, 16544562, 16544562], 'Item': ['Windex','Car Horn', 'Steering Wheel', 'Horse Feed', 'Bleech'
],'Cleaning_Supplies_Dept_Flag': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    'Automobile_Parts_Dept_Flag': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], 'Horse_Supplies_Dept_Flag': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]}
ex = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
ex
```

Essentially, My goal is drop  the Item name but keep the flags

- Final Product

```
d = {'Trans_ID': [149857724,  394875934, 16544562], 'Cleaning_Supplies_Dept_Flag': [1, 0, 1],
    'Automobile_Parts_Dept_Flag': [1, 0,1],
    'Horse_Supplies_Dept_Flag': [0,0,1]}
result = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
result
```

I have tried transposing, squeezing, stacking, and melting the dataframe; however, I am unable to get it the result format below.

Comment: why is there a 1 in 16544562/Automobile_Parts_Dept_Flag?

Answer (score 0):

```
#groupby and sum
out=ex.groupby('Trans_ID').sum().reset_index()
```

```
    Trans_ID    Cleaning_Supplies_Dept_Flag     Automobile_Parts_Dept_Flag  Horse_Supplies_Dept_Flag
0   16544562                              1                              0     1
1   149857724                             1                              1     0
2   394875934                             0                              1     0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to group by sum, because one transaction could get an item from two departments.

Answer (score 0):

You might want:

```
ex.groupby('Trans_ID', as_index=False, sort=False).max()
```

However the value for `16544562`/`Automobile_Parts_Dept_Flag` is different. Is this a mistake? Else, please explain the logic.

output:

```
    Trans_ID  Cleaning_Supplies_Dept_Flag  Automobile_Parts_Dept_Flag  Horse_Supplies_Dept_Flag
0  149857724                            1                           1                         0
1  394875934                            0                           1                         0
2   16544562                            1                           0                         1
```

Comment: The value for 16544562/Automobile_Parts_Dept_Flag is corrrect. Trans_ID bought two items from different departments. Example: I go to a store and buy from two items: Car part and Cleaning Supply. I check out at 1 register however, I actually shopped at two different departments in one transaction

Comment: @Zane but user `16544562` never bought an item from `Automobile_Parts_Dept_Flag`

Comment: I see what you are saying now. It was a typo. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: So you really want to aggregate the IDs with 1 of there is at least a 1, else 0?